# How to store 3-dimension tensor efficiently with certain symmetries?

Tags: tensors

I'm not sure if this is a math problem, but I've searched this question for a very long time and still can't find an answer. Turning to the math community for help is my last hope.

The 3-dimension tensor I need satisfies:

$A_{ijk} = A_{ikj} = A_{jik} = A_{jki} = A_{kij} = A_{kji}$

Certainly there is a way to save the matrix efficiently, using $\frac{1}{A_{3}^{3}} = \frac{1}{6}$ time space than just store it in $A[N][N][N]$. However, I can't work out the math for the indexing function. So is there a math or document on how to store and index symmetries tensor effectively? I would be grateful for any help!

I know exactly how to store 2-dimension symmetic metrix $A_{ij}$
, just allocate an array size of $(1+n)∗n/2$
(n is the length of a dimension) and using the function to get the index:

```
int getIndex(int p1, int p2) { 
    if (p1 > p2) { int tmp = p2; p2 = p1; p1 = tmp; } 
    return (1 + p1) * p1 / 2 + p2; 
}
```

But for 3-dimension tensor, I really have no idea..

Comment: A brute force method would be to manually create a dictionary taking said permutations to a single value. In the event that you're using more than one matrix $A$ for which this property holds, it may prove worth the initial spatial overhead, though the index call when using the dictionary may be unwanted overhead. Alternatively, you may take inspiration from the solution of the 2d problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187957/how-to-store-a-symmetric-matrix

Comment: Store only $A_{ijk}$ for $i\ge j\ge k$.

Comment: I know exactly how to store 2-dimension symmetic metrix $A_{ij}$, just allocate an array size of $(1+n)*n/2$(n is the length of a dimension) and using index function:
```
int getEdgeIndex(int p1, int p2) {
    if (p1 > p2) {
        int tmp = p2;
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = tmp;
    }
    return (1 + p1) * p1 / 2 + p2;
}
```
But for 3-dimension tensor, I really have no idea..